# Menu Dropdowns - I have a MooTools example, but how can I make it pure CSS?

Tags: css, mootools, drop-down-menu, css-transitions

I love how the main menu of this site drops down + fades in. There are a lot of drop-down plugins, etc out there but this particular implementation feels really smooth to me.

The problem is it's powered by Mootools and MenuMatic (http://greengeckodesign.com/menumatic) , but Im almost certain you can achieve the same effects with pure CSS.

I think the "fading" would be easy enough to accomplish with a CSS opacity transition, but im not sure how to 1) allow drop-downs to by dynamic in width and 2) "scroll into view" without breaking the markup around it. In past projects, I've gotten around this with a "left: -9999em" and the animation from -9999em to target location happens so quickly, no one knows any different... but that seems like a hack.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

```
p {
  height:0; overflow:hidden;
  transition: all 2s;
  opacity: 0; background: salmon;
  width: 25%;
}
a:hover + p{
  height:100px; 
  overflow:auto;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 2s;}
```

[Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/2025379)

You will need to tweak it and add vendor prefixes, of course.